# Number of triples in Jena Fuseki

Tags: jena, semantic-web, fuseki

I have to upload 3 billion triples but the maximum would seem to be 1.7 billion https://www.w3.org/wiki/LargeTripleStores#Jena_TDB_.281.7B.29

It's correct? What is the maximum number of triples I can load in fuseki?

Answer (score 1):

(FYI: None of that page is not kept up to date that I can see.)

3 billion is possible into TDB2.

There isn't a specific hard limit - the system just gets slower.
The database will be very big (it is data dependent and I don't have figures).

There are a number of bulk loaders for TDB2. The best choice depends on hardware.

In the next Apache Jena release, there is one specifically designed for large loads when loading to rotating disk on modest hardware (called colloquially "xloader").

Ask on the users@jena mailing list to talk to others who have worked with large datasets.

Comment: see https://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/WikiData_Import_2020-08-15 for an import with some 14 billion triples